# Junit test with Mockito: Error ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, junit, mockito

i am getting the following error during junit tests:

```html
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1284)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6cc7b4de
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:57)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:47)
```

My test code is the following:

```
public class DatabricksQueryExecutorTests {
@Test
public void testReadUnityTableDataAsJson() throws SQLException {
    // Create a mock DatabricksConfig object
    DatabricksConfig databricksConfig = new DatabricksConfig();
    databricksConfig.setHost("example.com");
    databricksConfig.setHttpPath("/api/2.0");
    databricksConfig.setAccessToken("your-access-token");
    databricksConfig.setUsername("your-username");

    // Create a mock SQL query
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";

    // Create a mock ResultSet with sample data
    ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true, false);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(ResultSetMetaData.class));
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount()).thenReturn(2);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(1)).thenReturn("column1");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(2)).thenReturn("column2");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("value1");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(2)).thenReturn("value2");

    // Create a mock Connection and Statement
    Connection connection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    Statement statement = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
    Mockito.when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    Mockito.when(connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlQuery)).thenReturn(resultSet);

    // Create an instance of DatabricksQueryExecutor
    DatabricksQueryExecutor queryExecutor = new DatabricksQueryExecutor();

    // Call the method under test
    JsonArray jsonArray = queryExecutor.readUnityTableDataAsJson(sqlQuery, databricksConfig);

    // Verify the result
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, jsonArray.size());
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    Assertions.assertEquals("value1", jsonObject.get("column1").getAsString());
    Assertions.assertEquals("value2", jsonObject.get("column2").getAsString());
}
```

}

I tried debugging the issue but unable to identify the issue as the code is failing in the ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class) step. How can i resolve the issue.
Any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Update: Code to test:

```html
public class DatabricksQueryExecutor {
public JsonArray readUnityTableDataAsJson(String sqlQuery, DatabricksConfig databricksConfig) throws SQLException {

    String host = databricksConfig.getHost();
    String httpPath = databricksConfig.getHttpPath();
    String accessToken = databricksConfig.getAccessToken();// Token generated from databricks profile page.
    String username = databricksConfig.getUsername();
   
    String jdbcString = String.format(
            "jdbc:databricks://%s:443;EnableArrow=0;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=%s;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=%s",
            host, httpPath, accessToken);

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcString, username, accessToken);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery)) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
                    String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                    String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);
                    jsonObject.addProperty(columnName, columnValue);
                }
                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            }
            return jsonArray;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Config:

```
public class DatabricksConfig {
@JsonProperty("host")
private String host;
@JsonProperty("httpPath")
private String httpPath;
@JsonProperty("accessToken")
private String accessToken;
@JsonProperty("username")
private String username;
```

}

Updates after fix to the error:

**Imports in test class**:

```html
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.data.test.dest.databricksqueryexecutor.model.DatabricksConfig;
```

**Junit dependency in POM:**

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Test output after performing : Run As : Junit Test:**

Finished after 0.118 seconds. Runs : 0/0 Errors: 0 Failures: 0
There is no output

**Update**: Removing the Junit 4 dependency, added Junit5.
Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException

```html
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:347)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at com.se.epx.dain.databricksqueryexecutor.DatabricksQueryExecutorTest.testReadUnityTableDataAsJson(DatabricksQueryExecutorTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: Hello! Please share the code you want to test and test class configurations

Comment: Hello @Feelfree: Updated the question with the details. Thanks

Comment: You have class dsexecutor and method named readTableDataAsJson. I don't see it in test. And where do you define or mock dataConfig?

Comment: Hello @Feelfree: i have updated the code with the actuals now. 
I have not mocked dataConfig. 
I am new to junit and mockito and learning the basics of it.

Comment: Check this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580745/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-when-trying-to-mock .In most cases, it could be a dependency issue.

Comment: Mockito version?

Comment: @Lesiak: the following:
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
 <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.2-beta</version>

<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.0</version>

Comment: Why are you mixing relatively new version of mockito with 2.0.2-beta from 2015. That is nearly 10 years old. mockito-junit-jupiter pulls mockito-core transitively, that is all what you need. Get rid of mockito-all and retry. If using an ide make sure it pulls the change. And lastly - you should be using test scope for your test dependencies.

Comment: @Lesiak: thanks a lot, removing the dependency resolved the error. But there is no output (pass/fail) to the Junit run. Its strange. Ive added the screenshot to the question

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont have access to post images:

Test result is something like this:
Finished after 0.118 seconds.
Runs : 0/0
Errors: 0
Failures: 0

Comment: Please post: 1. Imports in test class. 2. Junit dependency in pom. 3. Entire test output. You can edit your question, or add a new one.

Comment: Hello @Lesiak: edited the question to add the details.

Comment: added  <scope>test</scope> to junit dependency as well and tested, same results.

Comment: There is some mess in your dependencies and imports. You have both junit4 and junit5 in your dependencies. Pick only one (junit5 unless you have a good reason not to do so). Use jUnit5 imports. Make sure you have `junit-jupiter-engine`, not only `junit-jupiter-api`

Comment: @Lesiak: removed junit 4 dependency, added junit-jupiter-engine. 
Getting response now : java.util.NoSuchElementException

Added to the question

Comment: Your initial problem is solved - I added an answer. Now your problem is in Driver manager.getConnection - it is a static call which is not stubbed in test. If you want to go the mocking path, I suggest refactoring your code to use DataSource (passed to constructor) instead. Normally, using a real database (embedded or in docker container on your machine) in test is preferable to mocking - but I don't know what Databricks offers. This deserves a new, databrics specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem was caused by pulling outdated version of mockito - 2.0.2-beta from 2015 which is nearly 10 years old.