# Junit test: NoSuchElementException, Mock getConnection

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a JUnit test, but receiving java.util.NoSuchElementException. With limited knowledge of Mockito and JUnit, I understand DriverManager.getConnection needs to be mocked/stubbed. How can I do that?

The aim is to run the JUnit test without access to the actual database.

```java
public class DatabricksQueryExecutorTests {
    @Test
    public void testReadUnityTableDataAsJson() throws SQLException {
        // Create a mock DatabricksConfig object
        DatabricksConfig databricksConfig = new DatabricksConfig();
        databricksConfig.setHost("example.com");
        databricksConfig.setHttpPath("/api/2.0");
        databricksConfig.setAccessToken("your-access-token");
        databricksConfig.setUsername("your-username");

        // Create a mock SQL query
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";

        // Create a mock ResultSet with sample data
        ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
        Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true, false);
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(ResultSetMetaData.class));
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount()).thenReturn(2);
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(1)).thenReturn("column1");
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(2)).thenReturn("column2");
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("value1");
        Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(2)).thenReturn("value2");

        // Create a mock Connection and Statement
        Connection connection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        Statement statement = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
        Mockito.when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
        Mockito.when(connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlQuery)).thenReturn(resultSet);

        // Create an instance of DatabricksQueryExecutor
        DatabricksQueryExecutor queryExecutor = new DatabricksQueryExecutor();

        // Call the method under test
        JsonArray jsonArray = queryExecutor.readUnityTableDataAsJson(sqlQuery, databricksConfig);

        // Verify the result
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, jsonArray.size());
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        Assertions.assertEquals("value1", jsonObject.get("column1").getAsString());
        Assertions.assertEquals("value2", jsonObject.get("column2").getAsString());
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:347)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at com.se.epx.dain.databricksqueryexecutor.DatabricksQueryExecutorTest.testReadUnityTableDataAsJson(DatabricksQueryExecutorTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not trying to mock JDBC connections. Either test on a higher level, and only test the database in an integration test, or use something like testcontainers-java or similar to provide an actual database to test against.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your DatabricksQueryExecutor class to provide a full solution, but DriverManager.getConnection() is a static method and as such you will want to mock it similar to the the examples in here:

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

One of those examples is:

```
try (MockedStatic<StaticUtils> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticUtils.class)) {
        utilities.when(StaticUtils::name).thenReturn("Eugen");
        assertThat(StaticUtils.name()).isEqualTo("Eugen");
    }
```

You will want to replace StaticUtils with DriverManager and mock the getConnection method as above and return your mocked Connection object.

Comment: Ethan, thanks for the suggestion. I have the class here, was facing other issues before this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218660/junit-test-with-mockito-error-exceptionininitializererror?noredirect=1#comment137925782_78218660

Comment: Let us know how you get on with the above suggestion. Would recommend reading up on how MockedStatic works as well. You need to ensure your method under test sits within that block of code too. There is a great example doing the exact same thing in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you don't stub static `DriverManager.getConnection` in your test code.

Preferable way is to replace `DriverManager` with `DataSource`

See [DriverManager javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> The DataSource interface, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a DataSource object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source.

**Why is DataSource preferable?**

DriverManager.getConnection is a static method, while DataSource is an interface.

This means that `DriverManager.getConnection` always goes to actual implementation and pulls a new connection.

DataSource, being an interface, can be abstracted over, both in tests and in prod.

In tests:

- replace your DataSource with a mock (you dont have to use mockStatic, which is not very convenient, in terms of syntax and being thread local, and in the past was not available in Mockito)

In production, common use cases are:

- connection pooling
- logging

In all cases, you should pass DataSource to your service via constructor.

Comment: My answer addresses the mocking approach. You seem to be using DataBricks driver. "The Databricks JDBC Driver is used for direct SQL and HiveQL access to Apache
Hadoop / Spark, enabling Business Intelligence (BI), analytics, and reporting on
Hadoop / Spark-based data. The connector efficiently transforms an application’s SQL
query into the equivalent form in HiveQL, which is a subset of SQL-92. " The real question you should be asking is whether you can connect this driver to some local DB. I cannot help with that - this is DataBricks specific.

Comment: Lesiak: im not trying to connect to any specific source, this code is just to learn junit and mockito. The idea here is to mock whats possible. 
I want to check how would the mocking work and learn the process and see if the unit test works. 
There is nothing specific to trying to connect to a specific source.
Thanks

Comment: @User1515 Sure thing. But be aware that mocking is not always the right approach, and knowing what to mock is also sth to learn. From my experience, mocking JDBC API is complex and rarely finds bugs with DB interaction. You are better off creating a Repository class and mocking access methods (like `getAllMyTableEntities`). For testing actual queries, interacting with a non-mocked DB is likely to bring morre value

Comment: Lesiak, i appreciate ur point and agree with it. I will learn the points for sure. Just want to get this test working first. Im totally lost with the number of info in the various pages on stack overflow :)